# How do you close SO question as belonging in Code Review

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, migration

As title? 
Often I see questions in SO that appear to belong in CR. However often I am forced to close the question as being "Off Topic", "Primarily Opinion based".

This seems to be highly unhelpful. Since, although true, the question actually does have a place in CR.

I think that having your question closed as "Primarily Opinion Based" could be quite disheartening. Especially since I would be happy to give my opinion in CR.

Comment: you can use Custom reason for now and write : *this question is off-topic for stackoverflow because is about a code review*. You can provide a link to code review too. There is no belongs to another stackexchange site -> code review ; yet in place

Comment: Once [Codereview.SE] is out of beta, this migration path will most likly be created. (From what I've heard, the only reason why this path does not exist is because CR is still in Beta) - Mods can migrate to any side.

Comment: Code Review has [**already** been confirmed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191347/can-we-add-code-review-to-the-migration-list) as a off-topic target candidate, but the site must first come out of beta. It already is a very successful manual migration target.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay...thanks..also...kind of expected this to be closed as Dupe given that link.

Comment: Your question title wasn't *quite* a duplicate; it looks as if you are unaware that you can request moderators to migrate a question, for which there are other dupes. But the answer there does mention the option, *and* is specific about CR and the fact that it'll probably be added to The List when out of beta, so I've now VTCed as a dupe of that post, yes.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby: Tim Post, in the linked question, seems to suggest otherwise. 6% rejected is hardly 'most'. Or are you saying that the moderators on Stack Overflow are filtering out most requests?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: In that case my apologies, most suggestions for migration I have seen were wrong (sometimes just wrong and sometimes really, really wrong). I haven't seen a single *real* CR question on SO by now. But if the overall data says that this is not the case, then I'll stand corrected.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby: If *individual* users think non-working code is suitable for a CR migration, then that is not necessarily a problem; you still need at least 3 out of 5 votes to be for a specific target before it is migrated.